# Determine proper recurrence functions for divide and conquer algorithms

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, master-theorem

I have been trying to understand the nature of recurrences for quite a while. I am specifically curious about how the functions (T(n)) for recurrences are produced. For instance in mergesort it is stated that the time complexity can be said to be T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn. I fail to see the connection between this and the recursive calls in merge sort.

I understand the concept of the master theory. a should be the number of recursive calls, b should be the factor by which the input shrinks in each call, and d is the work done outside of the recursive algorithm. I just don't understand how any work in mergesort is done outside the recursive algorithm, given that all work done by the algorithm is spawned by one of the recursive calls in some way or another.

```
slice1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(u_arr, 0, half); // this takes O(n) time, better method?
slice2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(u_arr, half, u_arr.length);
        arr1 = this.mergesort(slice1);
        arr2 = this.mergesort(slice2);
        return this.merge(arr1, arr2);
    }
```

Excluding the base case, some initialization, and the merge function how could any work done by this algorithm be done outside of a recursive call? And given that running time outside of recursive calls can be determined, is the recurrence then just essentially a template function to plug in characteristics of divide and conquer algorithms such that a T(n/b) + O(n^d)? Given the appropriate a,b, and d.

Comment: Usually `cn` part of mergesort comes from the fact that `this.merge(arr1, arr2)` requires O(n)

Comment: think in terms of a single call: you call mergesort on left half, then on right half. now you have two sorted halves. you need to merge them into a single sorted array. this merging requires `O(n)` time

Comment: Ahh, thank you both that helps clarify things. I was thinking of T(n) as a running time of the entire algorithm instead of a single recursive call. Helps to see how the this.merge call is external to the recursive calls and appended as an addition in the function. Thank you!